# how could let NoClassDefFoundError exposed during compile stage

Tags: java, maven, noclassdeffounderror

Latest I encountered a bug in production environment, that is when user access some coupon list page, it had below error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/myapp/common/util/WrappedBeanCopier
```

And the maven dependency is like this

```
myapp
    - coupon
        - common 2.0
    - common 1.0
```

and the `WrappedBeanCopier` only in `common 2.0`, and myapp actually used is `common 1.0`, so caused this accident happen.

I want to know why it can be compiled and deployed to tomcat successfully? Have some manner could let it is exposed as soon as possible? e.g. compile failed.

Comment: The deployment had success as you have both the jar files you need. So dependencies are satisfied. But on runtime you could not choose in which order your jar are loaded from the web container. So if you have classes with the same name it could happen that you load the wrong class and going to find such *NoClassDefFoundError*.  In this [page](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) it explain how to avoid this situations by using exclusion in maven dependencies.

Comment: Compilation happens in one environment; execution happens in another. It is up to you to ensure that the classpath used during compilation is the same as the classpath during execution.

Answer (score 1):

**Getting notified about NoClassDefFoundError errors during compilation is unfortunately impossible.**

The reason for that is that the error itself exists to indicate this error:

*(excerpt from the javadoc of the Exception class)*

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to
>   load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or
>   as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no
>   definition of the class could be found.
>
> **The searched-for class definition existed when the currently executing
>   class was compiled, but the definition can no longer be found.**

So there is really no silver-bullet against this kind of error. The measures you can take to avoid it happening again:

- work out a more reliable dependency structure using Maven
- more thorough testing (there should be a testing phase, environment, etc. between compilation and production)
- even more testing, because this error can occur not only when a class definition has changed, you can also have a hard time with NoClassDefFoundErrors if your class cannot load due to an exception while initializing a static variable.

Example of a class that would never load:

```
private static Integer someThresholdValue = MyClass.calculateThreshold();

private static Integer calculateThreshold() {
   throw new Exception("some error occured");
}
```

*Note:
It can get super-nasty when that error above does not constantly occur, but only if the class was attempted to load at an early time in the boot-sequence of an application, where let's say the Spring context was not ready yet... So you would get a NoClassDefFoundError each time you are too eager to test, but if you wait 10 seconds before accessing your webapp, then it is all fine... Bad memories.*

Comment: Thanks! myapp is only a web layer as a gateway, all business logical and unit test are inner the dependent libs, e.g. coupon. So if exist some maven plugin could resolve this problem, at least could warn you the version of outer common is less than version of indirectly independent common.

Comment: As I said above: there is no silver-bullet. This is a complex problem, and you will not get away with finding some simple, all-covering solution. (some clever maven plugin, javac flags, etc)